# Could not load 'dijit.Menu'

Tags: dojo

I want to run Dojo/Dijit with the Google CDN:

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
         src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.3.2/dojo/dojo.xd.js">
</script>
```

I've tried 1.3.2, 1.3, 1.2 and all give this same problem. 
If what I've read is true, I only need to include the dojo.xd.js - then the requires will properly find dijit somehow relative to dojo.

In Firebug I see the following:

> http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.2/dijit/Menu.js
>   200 OK

I'm confused by this, because I if http status=200 is okay - then why is this line showing up in red?

The next line says

> could not load 'dijit.Menu';  last
>   tried '../dijit/Menu.js'

I had this working with all the Dojo/Dijit source code local - but I'm determined to get it running with the CDN.

I did some searches, and the best I could find was that Menu.js was included in certain releases, but I think they were talking 1.2 or before.

Same error occurs in the Chrome browser.

Thanks for helping.
Neal Walters

**More Info Added:**

Thanks for the example.  I took it and got a simple menu working:

http://3wcloud-com-provisioning-qa.appspot.com/testDijitMenuOnly

Here's the "beast" that I'm trying to get working.
http://3wcloud-com-provisioning-qa.appspot.com/testDijit

This was originally a copy of the Dojo Theme demo - and it was working when I was running with Dojo local.  It does a delayed/manual parse.

Like I said above, I tried 1.2, 1.3, 1.3.2 and so on, so it was just a matter of timing when I copyied/pasted into my question.

And OOPS - I didn't have djconfig - so I added that - but similar problem - just more explicit paths.

Thanks again - I'm going to love Dojo when I over these little humps.

This is the page I'm trying to reproduce: 
http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dijit/themes/themeTester.html?theme=soria

Comment: it's not a djConfig problem, see my answer about dijit.js and dijit-all.js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have something strange in your djConfig?  The fact that it's spitting out "../dijit/Menu.js" makes it seem like you have a path setting in there.

I set up a [simple demo page](http://jsbin.com/exeso) that uses the Google CDN and does:

```
dojo.require('dijit.Menu')
```

without problem.

Also, the script tag has 1.3.2 but it's loading menu from 1.2 which is strange.

Post a the full source code of what isn't working and that'll help track down the problem.

**EDIT AFTER POSTING LINK**

Remove these lines from your testDijit page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/dijit/dijit.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/dijit/dijit-all.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

**YET ANOTHER EDIT**

Call me crazy (since you don't seem to approve or upvote answers on SO making this a kind of no-op for me) but I got it working with the CDN [here.](http://jsbin.com/omoti).  It still has problems because the CDN doesn't have all the test files on it (dijitTest.css and countries.json for example).  You can download it and do a diff on your ow file to see what I changed.  I mostly added a bunch of missing requires and changed paths to CSS and images.  You also have a script tag referencing `/dojo.js` in your file.

I'm curious why you are so driven on getting the dijit tester running on your app since it seems like it'd be more fun/productive to learn dojo solving problems within your application.

Comment: See revisions - I edited my original question because ran out of space in comment.

Comment: Change completed - similar result.  That was junk left over when I was testing 100 permutations. 
 I've got to gym - need a mental break.  Thanks again.

Comment: I thought I upvoted all your answers that were on target - I'll go back and check.  Meanwhile I'll work through what you posted above.

Comment: Basically, I'm taking their full-blown sample, and removing things from it to become my menu/framework - where I put the content in the right panel.  So /testDijit is their sample reworked on GAE, and /testDijitMenu is where I have started to size it down to my needs.

Comment: I see you added these five ilnes:
  //added these five requires 
        dojo.require('dijit.PopupMenuItem');
        dojo.require('dijit.PopupMenuBarItem');
        dojo.require('dijit.layout.LinkPane');
        dojo.require('dijit.form.VerticalRuleLabels');
        dojo.require('dijit.form.VerticalRule'); 
The screen doesn't "paint" well without them.
How did the themeTester.html demo work without them? How did you know to add them? 

So removing the extra "junk" outdated/test <script src statements probably made the original error go away.   MUCHO GRACIAS AMIGO!

Comment: Neal, when an answer solves your problem, remember to accept it (use the checkmark icon below the number giving the up/down votes for the answer): that's fundamental SO etiquette!